# NSDate in ios conversion

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i wanto convert the string 2013-03-19 13:41:57 +0000 to this format Wed Feb 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) in iOS .please help me any help will be highly appreciated.

i tried some thing like  this:

```
    NSString * clippedString  = @"2013-03-19 13:41:57 +0000 ";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];



    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    date = [dateFormat dateFromString:clippedString];
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Google/SO, You will find everything there. I have answered same kind of questions dozen of times....

Comment: @ Anoop Vaidya so what ?.if u have answered give me your solution instead of telling you have answered

Comment: @user2168483: I didn't answer because, few days back, I got 5 downvotes on a correct answer. Reason was : that a dup, and I having 12K poiints should not answer. Check here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171495/delete-an-accepted-correct-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accepted the challenge :)

```
NSString *string=@"2013-03-19 13:41:57 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:string];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz zzzz"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: that helped me a lot thanks dude.for your kind knowledge it was not a challenge knowledge exchange :)